# Add to / Remove from Lightning Favourites using Apex or the APIs

Tags: apex, api, lightning-experience

In Lightning Experience, since Spring '17 there has been the ability for a user to favourite a record using the star icon in the top right hand corner.

Is anyone aware of any way to add to / remove from this favourites list using either Apex or the APIs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of the Winter '18 release you can now use the User Interface API to get a user's favorites, create a favorite, update a favorite, or delete a favorite. [Here is a link to the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_resources_favorites.htm).

For example, you can create a favorite by making a POST request to the `/ui-api/favorites` endpoint with this json as the body to favorite a list view:

```
{
  name: "Most Important Accounts",
  sortOrder: 1
  target: "00BR0000000tTTwMAM",
  targetType: "ListView"
}
```