# How to store Multiple unique User IDs when a User performs an operation on Account Record? How to maintain fav User separation for each account record

Tags: apex, trigger, soql, custom-field, account

I'm implementing a favourite functionality for Account Record where a Logged In User can mark an Account as favourite. But this feature has to be User specific. By this I mean a Current LoggedIn User (User 1) Logs in and Marks the Account as favourite and then he logs out. When User 2 logs in and checks "Favourite Accounts" section he should not see the Favourite Account that has been marked by User 1. For this approach I thought of Using a Rich Text Area field on Account Object (Unique_UserIdMapping__c) and an apex trigger (or Flow or REST Service etc) which for the current Logged In User whenever he creates or updates the record this Unique_UserIdMapping__c is set to the UserInfo.getUserId( ) (current user Id). So I created a dummy account and this field populated correctly with User 1 ID. But when I logged in with User 2 and updated the Account Industry field, I saw that the Unique_UserIdMapping__c field value of this dummy account record was updated from User 1 ID to the User 2 ID Value. I thought it would get appended as an additional comma separated value since Unique_UserIdMapping__c was a Rich Text Area.

Important Note: I already am using a Junction Object which is a mapping between User and Account. This would have solved my problem ideally as there would be 2 entries in the table for the account with 2 different Users so just another column in this table(basically a field on the Object) would help me to keep track. But I cannot use this Junction Object as this is a StandardObject - DelegatedAccount (External Managed Account). DelegatedAccount does not allow Editing Records as per salesforce documentation. I had tried creating this field in EMA. It got created. But when I had updated it in Apex it had thrown access error.

Is there any alternative to track User IDs uniquely for each account? because it may even happen that Both User 1 and User 2 favourite the same account and I need to check the list of IDs mapped to that Account record, and if the current logged In User ID exists in that list, I need to fetch that Account record.

I had tried the following, doesnt work. This simply updates the User 1 ID to User 2 ID if account is updated. Doesnt store it in a comma separated values or list. and then User 1 himself doesnt see the favourite account which he had marked initialy since now its Id 2.

```
public static void markAccount Favourite(List<Account> favAccs){
favAccs[0].Unique_UserIdMapping__c = UserInfo.getUserId();
update favAccs;
}


// Target helps to get Account fields from Delegated Account
//ManagedBy gets User to which the DelegatedAccount record is mapped

// getting favourite account only for the logged in User which (or if) he has marked favourite
public static List<DelegatedAccount> getFavAccount(){

List<DelegatedAccount> lis2 = new List<DelegatedAccount>();
List<DelegatedAccount> getAcc =[Select TargetId,Target.Name from DelegatedAccount where ManagedById = UserInfo.getUserId];

for(DelegatedAccount delAcc : getAcc){

if (delAcc.Target.Unique_UserIdMapping__c != UserInfo.getUserId()){
lis2.add(delAcc);

}
}
return lis2;
}
```

this code isn't working and my logic obviously fails. Is there any alternative?

Comment: _I'm implementing a favourite functionality for Account Record where a Logged In User can mark an Account as favourite_; https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.user_userdisplay_favorites.htm&type=5

Comment: Do you have a custom action to mark an account Favorite? Or are you using salesforce standard functionality to mark favorite?

Comment: Custom action. There is a favourite icon on lightning datatable onrowAction marking it as favourite

Comment: see https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/186383/add-to-remove-from-lightning-favourites-using-apex-or-the-apis for an OOTB solution

Comment: Actually if you really want to do this per user,  i would investigate using Custom Setting. You basically set the value for intividual users as this is hierarchy based and the value can be different for each user and you can even set one by default if you want.